# Javascript Multiline regualr expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I Want to match the content start with the  tag and ends with the  tag

i have used `match(/\<block\>(.*)\<\/block>/g);`

But its only works for one line  `<block>Data</block>`

Not for others

```
 <block>Data 
   can be here 
   </block>
```

Any suggestions please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Javascript` doesn't have DOTALL flag in its regex engine.

But Javascript way to make dot match newlines is:

```
string.match(/<block>([\s\S]*?)<\/block>/ig);
```

`[\s\S]` in place of `.` matches any character including newlines.

Comment: **+1** Can you Explain why you have added an unexplained `i` in there?

Comment: @connorspiracist: `i` was unintentional as OP appeared to be matching a block of XML data and I thought it would be safe to add `i` (can be taken out if not needed)

Comment: This will match from the first <block> to the last </block> in the entire string.

Comment: `dotAll` has been added to EcmaScript. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/dotAll#browser_compatibility for browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

You must replace the dot `.` by `[\s\S]` because the dot doesn't match newlines.

```
/<block>([\s\S]*?)<\/block>/g
```

An alternative is to use `[^<]*` if no other tags are nested:

```
/<block>([^<]*)<\/block>/g
```

However a code like this:

```
<block> abcd
    <block>efgh</block>
</block>
```

will fail with the first pattern, and you can't solve the problem with javascript regexes.